# How to use digital status stored in SQL database to find out device availability

Tags: sql, duration

I have some digital flags which are logged into InTouch Historian. I want to find out How long that signal stayed ON (Accumulatively). e.g.

```
DateTime                       Status
-------------------------------------
22/11/2016 15:33:00              1
22/11/2016 15:33:40              0
22/11/2016 15:34:25              1
22/11/2016 15:34:56              1
22/11/2016 15:35:30              1
22/11/2016 15:35:57              0
22/11/2016 15:36:42              0
22/11/2016 15:37:18              1
etc
```

So the question is how to calculate the total duration for which the signal was high(1)

Expected output:

```
22/11/2016 15:33:40 - 22/11/2016 15:33:00 = 40s
22/11/2016 15:35:57 - 22/11/2016 15:34:25 = 92s
```

so the output should be 132s or 2:12

Comment: plz show expected output

Comment: What database platform?

Comment: It is SQL Database and I need this to generate reports using SSRS

Comment: Your two example outputs are different, one of them must be incorrect, because the duration end is at status 0 for first example, status 1 for second example. Please write exact conditions to get exact answer.

Comment: you are right, I have corrected. Thanks

Comment: Every relational database is a "SQL database". SQL is a query language not a specific DBMS product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH StatusOn (LoggedDate)
AS(
SELECT
    th.LoggedDate
from 
    [dbo].[InTouchHistory] th
left join
    [dbo].[InTouchHistory] th2
    ON th2.LoggedDate = (SELECT MAX(LoggedDate) FROM [dbo].[InTouchHistory] 
                        WHERE [LoggedDate] < th.LoggedDate)
WHERE
    ISNULL(th2.Status, 0) = 0
    and th.Status = 1
)
SELECT 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(second, th1.LoggedDate, th2.LoggedDate))
FROM StatusOn th1
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[InTouchHistory] th2
    ON th2.LoggedDate = (SELECT MIN(LoggedDate) FROM [dbo].[InTouchHistory] 
                        WHERE [LoggedDate] > th1.LoggedDate AND Status = 0)
```

Comment: I have created test view and it works but start having problem when I implement above code for actual [Runtime].[dbo].[AnalogHistory] view. I have added Tagname Like expressions to the above code which would be the third column in the above table (view) to filter only required tags in the database. Any suggestions?